# Hide GET parameter from URL

Tags: php, url-rewriting, yii

How to hide URL GET parameters (http://domain.com/MyFirstYii/page?view=about). I've searched lot of posts. They all are saying about rewrite and URL manager, but i couldn't achieve what i want. :(

My scenario is,

I just want to hide the URL GET parameters.

Eg:

```
http://domain.com/MyFirstYii/page***?view=about***
```

I wanted to hide `***?view=about***`.

Then URL should look like this `http://domain.com/MyFirstYii/page`. Other pages like this `http://domain.com/MyFirstYii/post`. In a simple words my GET parameters should act like POST parameters.

Thanks in Advance.

Edit:

I want to create some rules in the **URLManager**, but what kind of rules will hide the GET parameter.

Comment: What is the problem with just using `POST` instead of `GET`?

Comment: That doesn't make any sense.  URLs are URLs; there is no other user-controlled data included in the HTTP request.  Consider using URL rewriting.

Comment: I wanted to use in the 'href' also. I can't use POST there?

Comment: You either rewrite the way browsers work, reload the page without the get parameters after loading it and processing the GET parameters or you POST the data. GET data is by definition passed as part of the request in the url

Comment: I want to create some rules in the URLManager, but what kind of rules will hide the GET parameter.

Comment: Can you provide us the controller and action name we're talking about here?

Comment: I´m also guessing you want http://domain.com/MyFirstYii/about instead of http://domain.com/MyFirstYii/page  . Am i right?

Comment: UserController and actionPage() { //My code... }

Comment: @MrSoundless : ok if i want like domain.com/MyFirstYii/page/about, then how could i modify my urlManager?

Comment: Like other users have hinted at, the whole point of GET parameters is that they are in the URL itself. You need to either use POST, or tell us what problem you are trying to solve by attempting to hide GET parameters.

Comment: @Dhanendran have a look at my answer to modify the URL

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**\w** in regexp means „word“ character and such url part as „my-prety-page“ will NOT match.
To hide GET params you must improve your urlManager rules. You can write such a rule for pages using SEF urls:

```
'<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>/<title:[^\/]*>/*' => '<controller>/view'
```

In this case when you enter url

```
http://example.com/page/12/my-prety-title
```

a Page controller will be called to perform view action with id and title as arguments. It is the same if you enter this url:

```
http://example.com/page/view?id=12&title=my-prety-title
```

The last part `/*` in rule allows to keep additional params. E.g. if your address is

```
http://example.com/user/55/john-doe-junior/foo/bar/
```

in `UserController`'s `actionView` you can write

```
echo '<pre>' ;
print_r($_GET);
echo '</pre>' ;
die();
```

and you'll see

```
Array
(
    [id] => 55
    [title] => john-doe-junior
    [foo] => bar
)
```

Answer (score 0):

uncomment  these line from main.php

```
'urlManager'=>array(
                        'urlFormat'=>'path',
                        'showScriptName'=>false,
                        'rules'=>array(
                                'MyFirstYii/post/<view>'=>'MyFirstYii/post', 
                                '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/view',
                                '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
                                '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
                        ),
                ),
```

And put .htaccess file in root directory of project and write following code

```
RewriteEngine on

# if a directory or a file exists, use it directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# otherwise forward it to index.php
RewriteRule . index.php
```

Comment: These all are the basic rewrite options, already i've uncommented these things. even it shows the 'site/page?view=about' URL

Comment: this only changes the url format and hides the index.php parameter

Comment: Yeah with this, i want to hide '?view=about' also. :(

Comment: you can't hide all parameters from url you may hide "?view=" from url.

Comment: @abhi : How to hide "?view="?

Comment: By using above code that i have posted you can hide "?view=".

and write url like this
http://domain.com/MyFirstYii/post/about

Answer (score 0):

Add this url rule to the top of your url rules:

```
'page/<view:\w>' => 'user/page'
```

I'm assuming the next:

- controller name: UserController
- action name: actionPage

If my assumptions are wrong, please provide the right controller name and action name, so I can fix the answer.

UPDATE:
fixed controller name based on comment

UPDATE2:

If you want this to work for all actions in your controller, use:

```
'<action:\w>/<view:\w>' => 'user/<action>'
```

Comment: My controller is 'UserController' and action name is 'page'

Comment: Changed that for you too :)

Comment: Also added a second rule, which you could use instead of the first one, based on your needs. Let me know how it works out since I can't test it here.

Answer (score -3):

If you intend to use GET and need these parameter, you can't hide it, as this is the way GET works. If you really need to hide the parameter, you must switch to POST, as then parameters will be passed in the request payload instead of in url.

Comment: he is saying he is dynamically placing url's in anchor tags. here no post method and get method works

Answer (score -3):

use post method instead of get....that's the best and efficient solution.

to follow up on your query check out this site:

[http://pure-essence.net/2007/06/29/simple-php-path-rewrite/]

Comment: using `GET` method is faster than `POST`. Hence, `POST` is not an efficient solution. The main advantage of `POST` is that it can hide sensitive information while being transferred and can help a large amount of data to be transferred.

Comment: Dude, please stop. There is nothing to POST here... I can't believe everyone is talking about using POST instead of GET. IT DOESN'T MAKE ANY SENSE!

Comment: @MrSoundless The OP's question first (before editing) was about `HIDING THE URL`. (see edit history http://stackoverflow.com/posts/17086732/revisions). Well, that should make sense to you now!

Comment: @KevinPaladin Even before the edit, it was obvious what he wanted.

Comment: I'm not here to start an argument but in SO questions are expected to be well explained and clear and that was not the case. And an answer suggesting a different solution does not deserve a downvote. It might also help other people too apart from the OP.

Comment: he is saying he is dynamically placing url's in anchor tags. here no post method and get method works