# Hide parameter (query string) in url (htaccess)

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, laravel-4

How to hide parameters (query_string) in URL but send them to page hidden, not visible in address bar 
example:

I have this:

```
   http://localhost/project/company/redeem/category/Shirts/18?category_id=18
```

I want:

```
   http://localhost/project/company/redeem/category/Shirts.html
```

But I want to get sent parameter in PHP `$_GET['sent']`

I tried to redirect to page with no parameters(no query_string) [R] and after that give page some parameters (silently) without [R] redirection (without changing address itself)

I tried to use RewriteRule in .htaccess with different flags and different ways but nothing worked

Please suggest.

Comment: I suggest using POST for what you're trying to do

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17086732/hide-get-parameter-from-url

Answer (score 0):

As far as i am aware you can only hide the parameter key (in this case 'category_id') using the RewriteEngine:

```
RewriteEngine On
```

Then use a RewriteRule like this

```
RewriteRule ^project/company/redeem/category/Shirts/18/(regex of whatever you expect for your parameter)$ project/company/redeem/category/Shirts/18.php?category_id=$1
```

Not sure if the first 18 is coincidence or always the same as the category_id value. If it is you can also use

```
RewriteRule ^project/company/redeem/category/Shirts/(regex of whatever you expect for your parameter)$ project/company/redeem/category/Shirts.php?category_id=$1
```

If you want to use $_GET the parameters have to be written to the url *somewhere*. You can only *try* to hide it.

For example if you know each category by a name you could put those into the url instead of numbers. Lets say category_id 18 is "V-Neck Unisex-Shirts" you could use a url like

```
http://localhost/project/company/redeem/category/Shirts/V-Uni
```

and tell your script to use category "V-Uni" instead of "18".
.htaccess:

```
RewriteRule ^project/company/redeem/category/Shirts/([a-zA-Z-]*)$ project/company/redeem/category/Shirts.php?category=$1
```