# how to get the current action id in Yii?

Tags: php, url, yii, action

I need a function to get the current action Id, for example if the url is `/controller/view/5` I want to get the `5` which is the action Id, how I can do that in Yii?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Current action id can be taken like this,

```
  $id = Yii::app()->request->getParam('id');// param name
```

Comment: this returns the action name!

Comment: Yes I want the parameter

Answer (score 1):

Your url is not consistent with the way Yii expects you to form a URL. The general form of a url is

```
http://www.application.com/your_controller/your_controller_action/parameter1_tag/parameter1_value/parameter2_tag/parameter2_value/.../parametern_tag/parametern_value
```

In your case:

```
 /controller/view/some_parameter_tag/5
```

if you want to hide the parameter_tag, you can customise your route, You can use 
  '/'=>'/view',

Look here for some examples:
[Hide GET parameter from URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17086732/hide-get-parameter-from-url)