# Remove id from url

Tags: php, mysql

I have few records in MySQL DB table.

Displayed those records with pagination PREV and NEXT.

Page ids are displaying in url bar.

> http://localhost/pagination.php?page=5

I don't want them while pagination clicking.

How can i do this?

Here is my code.

```
<?php
mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
mysql_select_db("moodle");

$per_page = 10;

$pages_query = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT('id') FROM question");
$pages = ceil(mysql_result($pages_query, 0) / $per_page);

$page = (isset($_GET['page'])) ? (int)$_GET['page'] : 1;
$start = ($page - 1) * $per_page;
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM question LIMIT $start, $per_page");
while($query_row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){
    echo $query_row['id']."<br />";
}

$prev = $page - 1;
$next = $page + 1;

echo "<a href='pagination.php?page=$prev'>Prev</a> ";


if($pages >= 1){
    for($x=1; $x<=$pages; $x++){
        echo '<a href="?page='.$x.'">'.$x.'</a> ';
    }
}
echo "<a href='pagination.php?page=$next'>Next</a> ";
?>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Hide GET parameter from URL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17086732/hide-get-parameter-from-url)

Comment: @StarShine, Actually i don't want action with url, i just want action in the code only. I would like to integrate it in CMS Home page. could you plz guide me, what to delete from my code?

Answer (score 1):

Use id in session and don't display it in url . other method is to use Ajax call in pagination on click of previous or next button . i think these are two simple solutions for you that you can easily manage .

Comment: got the code for Pagination using Ajax. Thanks for the suggestion. Trying to integrate into my CMS. It is not effecting to url.

Comment: great. hope you will get perfect solution